# Flow chart generation using any programming language

Tags: javascript, python, flowchart

I have an excel sheet which looks like

[image]

I want to generate a flowchart for each feature.
Please suggest any library available so that I can generate the flowchart from the inputs in excel sheet.

Note: I have 20+ features and 10+ input/output flags.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0):

If by flowchart you mean a diagram of tranitions (for example), then a python-based solution is the Networkx library. Another viable alternative is Plotnine, yet it can be a bit trickier to master.